"Counterexample" of Auslander–Buchsbaum formula
The Auslander–Buchsbaum formula says that for an $R$-module $M$, its projective dimension plus the depth equals the dimension of $R$ (assuming $R$ is regular):
$$pd(M)+depth(M)=\dim(R).$$
However, if one choose $R$ be the local ring of $k[x,y,z]_{(x,y,z)}$, $I=(x^2,xy)$, and $M=R/I$, we have a length-two free-resolution
$$R\xrightarrow{\begin{bmatrix}y\\-x\end{bmatrix}} R^2\xrightarrow{[x^2\ xy]}R\to R/(x^2,xy).$$
Hence $pd(M)\le 2$. So depth is $$depth(M)=\dim(R)-pd(M)=3-pd(M)\ge 1.$$
This, according to the Serre criterion ($R_0+S_1$), implies that $M$ is reduced. However it is obviously not, since $I=(x,y)^2\cap (x)$ has an associated prime.
I wonder where the contradiction is.

@KReiser By google search, I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703498/depth-of-r-i-as-an-r-module-versus-as-a-ring

@AGlearner The depth of $M$ is indeed one, but why should it satisfy Serre's condition $(S_1)$?

@metalspringpro That's a good point! I only checked $S_1$ for maximal ideal, and according to cqfd's answer, it looks like this is exactly where I missed.

The ring $A=R/I$ does not satisfy $S_1$. Note that the associated primes of $A$ are $(x,y)$ and $(x)$. When we localize $A$ at $\mathfrak p=(x,y)$, $\mathfrak p R_\mathfrak p$ is still an associated prime of $A_\mathfrak p$, so $\operatorname{depth} A_\mathfrak p=0$. But $\dim A_\mathfrak p=1$, so $S_1$ is not satisfied.
(I am using the following as my definition of $S_n$: $\operatorname{depth} A_\mathfrak p\geq \min(n,\dim A_\mathfrak p)$ for all $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)$.)
